# Bootstrap popover com table-responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabela-html

Eu estou a utilizar o Bootstrap v3. E preciso de filtrar os campos das tabelas. Optei por usar [este exemplo](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Pretty-Table-Filter-Plugin-With-jQuery-Bootstrap-Filterable/) como base.

Estou agora com um problema, quando estou a visualizar a minha tabela (é table-responsive) num dispositivo móvel, o que acontece é que a caixa do filtro desaparece porque fica "dentro da tabela", podem ver nas imagens abaixo:

**Desktop**

[image: img1]

**Móvel**

[image: img2]

Tenho aqui um exemplo do meu código:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table id="example-table" class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
      <th> Campo x

        <!--DEPOIS DE APLICADO O FILTRO BEGIN-->   
        <i data-original-title="Filtro para &quot;Campo x&quot;"
        class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter filterable editable editable-click editable-empty editable-open"
        data-name="0" title="">
        </i>
        <div class="popover editable-container editable-popup fade bottom in">
            <div class="arrow"></div>
            <h3 class="popover-title">Filtro para "Campo x"</h3>
            <div class="popover-content">
                <div>
                    <form style="" class="form-inline editableform">
                        <div class="control-group form-group">
                            <div>
                                <div style="position: relative;" class="editable-input">
                                    <input style="padding-right: 24px;"
                                        class="form-control input-sm" type="text"><span
                                        style="display: none;" class="editable-clear-x"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="editable-buttons">
                                    <button type="submit"
                                        class="btn btn-primary btn-sm editable-submit">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                                    </button>
                                    <button type="button"
                                        class="btn btn-default btn-sm editable-cancel">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div style="display: none;" class="editable-error-block help-block"></div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <!--DEPOIS DE APLICADO O FILTRO END--> 
      </th>
    ...
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    ...
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('#example-table').filterable();
```

**jsfiddle**

[Outro exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/PfHab/10/)

[Mais um exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/6jd2U/3/)

Já andei a pesquisar em todo lado e não encontro nada sobre o assunto.
O que se está a passar e o como posso resolver o assunto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após duas semanas de pesquisas e de tentar tudo o que sei, finalmente consegui resolver o problema.

No meu caso adicionei aos valores por defeito do ***popover*** uma opção na linha 1392 do script
**bootstrap-editable.js**

linha   codigo

```
1      /*! X-editable - v1.5.1 
.
...
1390   mode: 'popup'      ,
1391
1392   container: 'body'
```

Assim o popover deixa de estar "dentro da tabela" e passa a pertencer ao *body*, assim sendo, fica a frente dos outros objetos.

A minha referencia: [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_popover_plugin.htm)